# How to play a card game we called Queens

Tags: identify-this-game

We used to play a game we called Queens - 3+ players. Everyone was dealt a hand of 7 cards, plus a dummy hand was dealt, after all the Queens were taken out and put into the main deck.

We started with lowest red (aces counted as low cards?) and players continued to play around the table if they could follow on this card in sequence. Once this 'run' was over the next player played their lowest black. If you managed to play a Queen it was put to the side of your 'played' cards.

I believe if you couldn't play you had to pick a card up from the main pack. The first player to play all their cards won - plus a bonus if your Queen was the same suit as the top card of the dummy hand as it was turned over at the end of the game. I recall it being good if you had a card below those being played, since you could start a new sequence with this one and no-one had the next card, meaning you could start another potential run with either your lowest black or red (a colour different to the one you'd just played).

This is all I can remember about this game, but I'm positive I've missed something important out in this description. Is anyone able to fill in my missing blanks, please?

Answer (score 1):

These types of games where you try to play all your cards (similar to Uno, Crazy 8's, etc.) are called shedding type card games, if you're looking on wikipedia or boardgamegeek that will get you started down the rabbit hole.

I haven't found any that specifically have the bonus queens that you remember though. Usually they have additional rules where Aces or Kings act as skips or reverses and such like you'd see in Uno. It's highly possible that you played a homemade variant of one such game.

From googling, it looks like there is a game marketed as Crazy Queens where their queens are worth bonus points, but it's played ~3 decks worth of cards. Although a home variant probably could probably be played with a standard deck.

A lot of these types of games have actual scoring by when played by kids just end when someone runs out of cards without the scoring actually being figured up.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question and looks like it is a reply to the question.

Comment: maybe it's not super clear but I think they were playing a home variant of crazy queens, but wanted to provide the tools for them to investigate further because that might not feel like a complete answer.

Comment: That would still be a comment as it doesn't provide an answer of how to play the game.

Comment: Good point. As it was tagged identify this game, I was approaching it as them being unable to locate the instructions because they didn't know what it was called. I'm currently on a firewalled connection with limited internet access, but I'll see if I can find an actual copy of the rules to post, although they obviously were playing with home variant rules so I'll be of limited utility since most similar games have the same basic rules.